# HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request (via wget)

Tags: postman, http-headers, wget, request-headers

Im trying to request a bank url using wget/postman and i got 400 response :

```
>wget --load-cookies /home/testauto/nxdh/cookies.txt https://www.bundesbank.de/statistic-rmi/StatisticDownload?tsId=BBK01.ST0334&tsId=BBK01.WT4623&tsId=BBK01.WT4624&sId=BBK01.WT4627&tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0203.R.A.A._Z._Z.A&tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0304.R.A.A._Z._Z.A&tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0405.R.A.A._Z._Z.A&tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0506.R.A.A._Z._Z.A&tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0607.R.A.A._Z._Z.A&tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0708.R.A.A._Z._Z.A&tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0809.R.A.A._Z._Z.A&tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0910.R.A.A._Z._Z.A&mode=its&its_csvFormat=de&its_currency=default&its_dateFormat=default&its_from=2023-09-21&its_to=2023-09-28
[1] 28177
[2] 28178
[3] 28179
[4] 28180
[5] 28181
[6] 28182
[7] 28183
[8] 28184
[9] 28185
[10] 28186
[11] 28187
[12] 28188
[13] 28189
[14] 28190
[15] 28191
[16] 28192
[17] 28193
--2023-09-28 19:24:27--  https://www.bundesbank.de/statistic-rmi/StatisticDownload?tsId=BBK01.ST0334
[2]   Done                    tsId=BBK01.WT4623
[3]   Done                    tsId=BBK01.WT4624
[4]   Done                    sId=BBK01.WT4627
[5]   Done                    tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0203.R.A.A._Z._Z.A
[6]   Done                    tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0304.R.A.A._Z._Z.A
[7]   Done                    tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0405.R.A.A._Z._Z.A
[8]   Done                    tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0506.R.A.A._Z._Z.A
[9]   Done                    tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0607.R.A.A._Z._Z.A
[10]   Done                    tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0708.R.A.A._Z._Z.A
[11]   Done                    tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0809.R.A.A._Z._Z.A
[12]   Done                    tsId=BBSIS.D.I.UMR.RD.EUR.MFISX.B.X100.R0910.R.A.A._Z._Z.A
[13]   Done                    mode=its
[14]   Done                    its_csvFormat=de
[15]   Done                    its_currency=default
[16]-  Done                    its_dateFormat=default
[17]+  Done                    its_from=2023-09-21
/home/testauto/nxdh >Resolving www.bundesbank.de (www.bundesbank.de)... 185.173.228.8
Connecting to www.bundesbank.de (www.bundesbank.de)|185.173.228.8|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 303 See Other
Location: /.enodia/challenge?redirect=%2Fstatistic-rmi%2FStatisticDownload%3FtsId%3DBBK01.ST0334 [following]
--2023-09-28 19:24:27--  https://www.bundesbank.de/.enodia/challenge?redirect=%2Fstatistic-rmi%2FStatisticDownload%3FtsId%3DBBK01.ST0334
Reusing existing connection to www.bundesbank.de:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2023-09-28 19:24:27 ERROR 400: Bad Request.


[1]+  Exit 8                  wget --load-cookies /home/testauto/nxdh/cookies.txt https://www.bundesbank.de/statistic-rmi/StatisticDownload?tsId=BBK01.ST0334
```

But using the browser, im able to download the file even if the first response is 400 :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmfWT.png)

i copied the cookies and add i to the wget command but still not work

Any recommandation please ?

i copied the cookies from the browser and add i to the wget command but still not work